# SSL error while reading stream; tls_error='SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown , location='/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf:40:9'

Tags: ssl, syslog, syslog-ng

I have installed syslog-ng for syslog over TLS using the instructions from [syslog-ng Open Source Edition 3.16 - Mutual authentication using TLS](https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.16/mutual-authentication-using-tls#TOPIC-956369).

I am using my DUT as client and debian PC as syslog server, but when i loading the cacert.pem on my DUT, i am geeting below error in syslog messages.

```
Jul 14 02:46:29 my-pc syslog-ng[6998]: Syslog connection accepted; fd='15', client='AF_INET(10.20.7.57:53524)', local='AF_INET(10.2.9:514)'
Jul 14 02:46:29 my-pc syslog-ng[6998]: SSL error while reading stream; tls_error='SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown , location='/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf:40:9'
Jul 14 02:46:29 my-pc syslog-ng[6998]: Error reading RFC6587 style framed data; fd='15', error='Connection reset by peer (104)'
Jul 14 02:46:29 my-pc syslog-ng[6998]: Syslog connection closed; fd='15', client='AF_INET(10.20.7.57:53524)', local='AF_INET(10.20.:514)'
```

I tried to reinstalled the syslog-ng but still same issue i am facing, could any one please help

Comment: I am using same config as mentioned in below